# Tabular and data.table

Tags: r, data.table, tabular

`tabular` from `tables` package works fine with `data.frame`:

```
tabular(a~c,data=data.frame(a=sample(letters[4:5],100,replace = T), b=rnorm(1000), c = sample(LETTERS[1:3],100,rep=T)))
```

But not with `data.table`:

```
tabular(a~c,data=data.table(a=sample(letters[4:5],100,replace = T), b=rnorm(1000), c = sample(LETTERS[1:3],100,rep=T)))
```

However, the following works:

```
tabular(a~c,data=data.table(data.frame(a=sample(letters[4:5],100,replace = T), b=rnorm(1000), c = sample(LETTERS[1:3],100,rep=T))))
```

Although the following can fix the problem:

```
tabular(factor(a)~factor(c),data=data.table(a=sample(letters[4:5],100,replace = T), b=rnorm(1000), c = sample(LETTERS[1:3],100,rep=T)))
```

But seems like there is something wrong with `tabular` or `data.table`?

Comment: From which package `tabular` comes? Please edit your question.

Comment: Well, the documentation of tabular says the argument should be one of "dataframe, list or environment".

Comment: If `tabular` requires `factor`s, note that `data.table` does not covert characters to factors by default, which `data.frame` does. This might describe the difference in behavior.

Comment: `tablular` can get *really* slow. might as well just use data frames